# Messed up my perl install on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, permissions, reinstall, perl

I have messed up my perl install on Mac OS X 10.6. I'll explain how:
I wanted to add a cpan package for Bundle::DBD::mysql, cpan told me to update Bundle::CPAN first. I couldn't because of permissions. So I `sudo`ed `perl -MCPAN -e shell` and updated cpan, then I got the mysql bundle, but it failed some tests, which I then forced the install (it works btw). Then for some reason I decided to rebuild the mysql bundle. This took a long long time. Eventually I realized it had rebuilt a lot, like perldoc.

Now whenever I try and run perldoc I haven't the permission to do so, but when I sudo perldoc to tells me it can't find it.

```
dlamblins-macbook:~ dlamblin$ perldoc
-bash: /usr/bin/perldoc: Permission denied
dlamblins-macbook:~ dlamblin$ sudo perldoc
Password:
sudo: perldoc: command not found
dlamblins-macbook:~ dlamblin$ sudo /usr/bin/perldoc
Password:
sudo: /usr/bin/perldoc: command not found
```

I'd like to reinstall perl for real the way Apple installed it when I updated to Snow Leopard (though keeping DBD::mysql would be nice), and I don't know where to start. I do not want to go with some fink package or ports styled system. Getting the latest perl 5.10 would be a plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may seem like I'm a total Mac Newb (though I've used a Mac since the LC) but since installing the combined update for 10.6.2 didn't fix this issue even though it overwrote the files, I realized belatedly that Disk Utility's "Repair Permissions" button would fix it. And it did.

The odd thing is the actual binary `/usr/bin/perldoc` wasn't touched. It's probably got something to do with one of those bundles in the output.

Here's what it output as it fixed stuff (note the last line is a ? for me)

```
Repairing permissions for “Macintosh HD”
Permissions differ on "private/etc/postfix/main.cf.default", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -r--r--r-- .
Repaired "private/etc/postfix/main.cf.default".
Permissions differ on "usr/bin/c2ph", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are -rw-rw-rw- .
Repaired "usr/bin/c2ph".
Permissions differ on "usr/bin/config_data", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are -r-xr-xr-x .
Repaired "usr/bin/config_data".
Permissions differ on "usr/bin/cpan", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are -r-xr-xr-x .
Repaired "usr/bin/cpan".
Permissions differ on "usr/bin/enc2xs", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are -r-xr-xr-x .
Repaired "usr/bin/enc2xs".
Permissions differ on "usr/bin/instmodsh", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are -r-xr-xr-x .
Repaired "usr/bin/instmodsh".
Permissions differ on "usr/bin/piconv", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are -r-xr-xr-x .
Repaired "usr/bin/piconv".
Permissions differ on "usr/bin/prove", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are -r-xr-xr-x .
Repaired "usr/bin/prove".
Permissions differ on "usr/bin/shasum", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are -r-xr-xr-x .
Repaired "usr/bin/shasum".
Permissions differ on "usr/share/derby", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Repaired "usr/share/derby".
Permissions differ on "Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/NetSNMP/default_store.pm", should be -rw-rw-r-- , they are -r--r--r-- .
Repaired "Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/NetSNMP/default_store.pm".
Permissions differ on "Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/NetSNMP/default_store/autosplit.ix", should be -rw-rw-r-- , they are -r--r--r-- .
Repaired "Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/NetSNMP/default_store/autosplit.ix".
Permissions differ on "Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/NetSNMP/default_store/default_store.bundle", should be -rwxrwxr-x , they are -r-xr-xr-x .
Repaired "Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/NetSNMP/default_store/default_store.bundle".
Warning: SUID file "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent" has been modified and will not be repaired.

Permissions repair complete
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) to run the appropriate Installer package from your 10.6 disc. I am not sure which package it is off the top of my head, but Pacifist lets you browse and search  the packages on disc. I don't believe it will remove new files, but it'll restore your Perl installation to the working default. You can also selectively extract files and folders.

[image: Using Pacifist to search for "Perl" on the Mac OS X 10.6 disc.]

I used it a couple of years ago to do damage control (quite successfully, I might add) following a rather embarrassing incident involving `sudo rm -fr /bin`. Don't ask.

Answer (score 2):

Yep...Disk Utilities "Repair Permissions" worked for me as well.  Same problem...installed the DBD::mysql module and it hosed up the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can always download the latest perl from http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/latest.tar.bz2.

You'll need to unarchive, and run Configure.

I personally usually prefer having my own installation of perl, even when the basic OS included a version. That means that my scripts can be upgraded to later versions on my schedule, not the maintainers.

Comment: It's not a particularly good idea to overwrite the default Perl installation with a custom one, since software updates and the like may make assumptions regarding the default system Perl. If you're going to roll your own Perl, it's best to install it to /usr/local or another out-of-the-way location.

In any case, he's still going to have to fix his system Perl.

Comment: I wouldn't overwrite the default installation, I meant install a new installation in a separate directory.

Comment: Gotcha, but that still doesn't fix his broken default Perl.

Comment: Regarding overwriting the default perl, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992720/perl-strategy-for-a-new-snow-leopard-user/1992934#1992934

Answer (score 1):

maybe it helps to install the latest update under http://support.apple.com/kb/DL959.
i had massive problems after an full system restore with time machine. it seems that this corrupts many things and i couldn't use quicklook anymore besides other stuff.
after reinstalling this update all functions as normal.
with a little bit of luck perl is in this update.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. It did however fix the mysterious hard-hanging flash plugin which had been the bane of youtube (and other flash video) since updating to the improved "safari plugin stability". Re-installing resolved this, but not my perldoc permission issue.

Comment: Actually this flash plug in stability thing comes and goes; it goes with a restart and I don't know what causes it yet.

Comment: For the interested: the flash stability had to do with audio in flash video and an incompatibility in Audio Hijack Pro. See: http://superuser.com/questions/83315/

Answer (score 0):

Installed fresh CPAN on Lion.

Before Disk Utility's "Repair Permissions":

```
$ perldoc
-bash: /usr/bin/perldoc: Permission denied
```

Works again after:

```
$ perldoc
Usage: perldoc5.12 [-h] [-V] [-r] [-i] [-D] [-t] [-u] [-m] [-n nroffer_program] [-l] [-T] [-d output_filename] [-o output_format] [-M FormatterModuleNameToUse] [-w formatter_option:option_value] [-L translation_code] [-F] [-X] PageName|ModuleName|ProgramName
       perldoc5.12 -f PerlFunc
       perldoc5.12 -q FAQKeywords
       perldoc5.12 -v PerlVar

The -h option prints more help.  Also try "perldoc perldoc" to get
acquainted with the system.                        [Perldoc v3.15_02]
```