# iTunes 9.0.2 hangs on launch on Mac OS X 10.6.2

Tags: itunes, safari, freeze

My [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) 9.0.2 hangs on launch in [OS X](http://www.apple.com/osx/) 10.6.2. This doesn't happen all the time, only if I've been running for a while. Then it will recur until I restart. Similarly [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/) 4.0.4 will hang in the flash player plugin when about to play a video. If I restart both these problems go away until later.

Based on this crash dump I am suspecting [Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/). I will try to install a newer version of the driver involved, but so far I haven't had much luck.

I have [uninstalled](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html) the [Flash Plugin](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) (10.0.r42 and r32) but clearly I want it in the long run.

This is iTunes' crash report.

```
Date/Time:       2009-12-14 19:56:02 -0500
OS Version:      10.6.2 (Build 10C540)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  6

Command:         iTunes
Path:            /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
Version:         9.0.2 (9.0.2)
Build Version:   2
Project Name:    iTunes
Source Version:  9022501
Parent:          launchd [120]

PID:             16878
Event:           hang
Duration:        3.55s (sampling started after 2 seconds)
Steps:           16 (100ms sampling interval)

Pageins:         5
Pageouts:        0


Process:         iTunes [16878]
Path:            /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
UID:             501

  Thread 8f96000   
  User stack:
    16 ??? (in iTunes + 6633) [0x29e9]
      16 ??? (in iTunes + 6843) [0x2abb]
        16 ??? (in iTunes + 11734) [0x3dd6]
          16 ??? (in iTunes + 44960) [0xbfa0]
            16 ??? (in iTunes + 45327) [0xc10f]
              16 ??? (in iTunes + 2295196) [0x23159c]
                16 ??? (in iTunes + 103620) [0x1a4c4]
                  16 ??? (in iTunes + 105607) [0x1ac87]
                    16 ??? (in iTunes + 106442) [0x1afca]
                      16 OpenAComponent + 433 (in CarbonCore) [0x972e9dd0]
                        16 CallComponentOpen + 43 (in CarbonCore) [0x972ebae7]
                          16 CallComponentDispatch + 29 (in CarbonCore) [0x972ebb06]
                            16 DefaultOutputAUEntry + 319 (in CoreAudio) [0x70031117]
                              16 AUGenericOutputEntry + 15273 (in CoreAudio) [0x7000e960]
                                16 AUGenericOutputEntry + 13096 (in CoreAudio) [0x7000e0df]
                                  16 AUGenericOutputEntry + 9628 (in CoreAudio) [0x7000d353]
                                    16 ??? [0xe0c16d]
                                      16 ??? [0xe0fdf8]
                                        16 ??? [0xe0e1e7]
                                          16 ahs_hermes_CoreAudio_init + 32 (in Instant Hijack Server) [0x13fc7e9]
                                            16 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x9798e922]
  Kernel stack:
    16 semaphore_wait_continue + 0 [0x22a0a5]

  Thread 9b9eb7c   
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 34 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x979bbe42]
      16 _pthread_start + 345 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x979bbfbd]
        16 ??? (in iTunes + 4011870) [0x3d475e]
          16 CFRunLoopRun + 84 (in CoreFoundation) [0x993497a4]
            16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452 (in CoreFoundation) [0x99343864]
              16 __CFRunLoopRun + 2079 (in CoreFoundation) [0x9934477f]
                16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x9798e8da]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 9bc8b7c   
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 30 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x979b4336]
      16 _pthread_wqthread + 390 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x979b44f1]
        16 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 234 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x979b4a68]
          16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x979b4cc3]
            16 kevent + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x979b50ea]
  Kernel stack:
    16 kevent + 97 [0x471745]

  Binary Images:
      0x1000 -   0xbecfea  com.apple.iTunes 9.0.2 (9.0.2) <1F665956-0131-39AF-F334-E29E510D42DA> /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
   0x13f6000 -  0x1402ff7  com.rogueamoeba.audio_hijack_server.hermes 2.2.2 (2.2.2) <9B29AE7F-6951-E63F-616A-482B62179A5C> /usr/local/hermes/modules/Instant Hijack Server.hermesmodule/Contents/MacOS/Instant Hijack Server
  0x70000000 - 0x700cbffb  com.apple.audio.units.Components 1.6.1 (1.6.1) <600769A2-479A-CA6E-A214-C8766F7CBD0F> /System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/MacOS/CoreAudio
  0x97284000 - 0x975a3fe7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.2 (861.2) <A9077470-3786-09F2-E0C7-F082B7F97838> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
  0x9798e000 - 0x97b32feb  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <D45B91B2-2B4C-AAC0-8096-1FC48B7E9672> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
  0x99308000 - 0x9947ffef  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.1 (550.13) <AE9FC6F7-F0B2-DE58-759E-7DB89C021A46> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation


Process:         AirPort Base Station Agent [142]
Path:            /System/Library/CoreServices/AirPort Base Station Agent.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPort Base Station Agent
UID:             501

  Thread 8b1d3d4    DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 ??? (in AirPort Base Station Agent + 5344) [0x1000014e0]
      16 ??? (in AirPort Base Station Agent + 70666) [0x10001140a]
        16 CFRunLoopRun + 70 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e859b6]
          16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
            16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
              16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 8b80000    DispatchQueue 2
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 _pthread_wqthread + 353 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886bb8]
        16 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 244 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87887286]
          16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8788775c]
            16 kevent + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87885bba]
  Kernel stack:
    16 kevent + 97 [0x471745]

  Thread 6e3c7a8   
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 __workq_kernreturn + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878869da]
  Kernel stack:
    16 workqueue_thread_yielded + 562 [0x4cb6ae]

  Thread 8b0f3d4   
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5e41]
      16 _pthread_start + 331 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5f8e]
        16 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878b09e2]
  Kernel stack:
    16 sleep + 52 [0x487f93]

  Thread 8bcb000   
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5e41]
      16 _pthread_start + 331 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5f8e]
        16 ??? (in AirPort Base Station Agent + 71314) [0x100011692]
          16 ??? (in AirPort Base Station Agent + 13712) [0x100003590]
            16 ??? (in AirPort Base Station Agent + 71484) [0x10001173c]
              16 __semwait_signal + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a79ee]
  Kernel stack:
    16 semaphore_wait_continue + 0 [0x22a0a5]

  Binary Images:
         0x100000000 -        0x100016fff  com.apple.AirPortBaseStationAgent 1.5.4 (154.2) <73DF13C1-AF86-EC2C-9056-8D1946E607CF> /System/Library/CoreServices/AirPort Base Station Agent.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPort Base Station Agent
      0x7fff86e3b000 -     0x7fff86faeff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.1 (550.13) <1E952BD9-37C6-16BE-B2F0-CD92A6283D37> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
      0x7fff8786c000 -     0x7fff87a2aff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib


Process:         AppleSpell [3041]
Path:            /System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/Contents/MacOS/AppleSpell
UID:             501

  Thread 999a000    DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 ??? (in AppleSpell + 5852) [0x1000016dc]
      16 ??? (in AppleSpell + 6508) [0x10000196c]
        16 -[NSSpellServer run] + 72 (in Foundation) [0x7fff81d3b796]
          16 CFRunLoopRun + 70 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e859b6]
            16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
              16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
                16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 8a9e7a8    DispatchQueue 2
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 _pthread_wqthread + 353 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886bb8]
        16 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 244 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87887286]
          16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8788775c]
            16 kevent + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87885bba]
  Kernel stack:
    16 kevent + 97 [0x471745]

  Binary Images:
         0x100000000 -        0x1000a9fef  com.apple.AppleSpell 1.6.1 (61.1) <6DE57CC1-77A0-BC06-45E7-E1EACEBE1A88> /System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/Contents/MacOS/AppleSpell
      0x7fff81cbc000 -     0x7fff81f3dfe7  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.1 (751.14) <767349DB-C486-70E8-7970-F13DB4CDAF37> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
      0x7fff86e3b000 -     0x7fff86faeff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.1 (550.13) <1E952BD9-37C6-16BE-B2F0-CD92A6283D37> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
      0x7fff8786c000 -     0x7fff87a2aff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib


Process:         autofsd [52]
Path:            /usr/libexec/autofsd
UID:             0

  Thread 79933d4    DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 ??? (in autofsd + 5340) [0x1000014dc]
      16 ??? (in autofsd + 6461) [0x10000193d]
        16 CFRunLoopRun + 70 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e859b6]
          16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
            16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
              16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 75997a8    DispatchQueue 2
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 _pthread_wqthread + 353 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886bb8]
        16 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 244 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87887286]
          16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8788775c]
            16 kevent + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87885bba]
  Kernel stack:
    16 kevent + 97 [0x471745]

  Binary Images:
         0x100000000 -        0x100001ff7  autofsd ??? (???) <29276FAC-AEA8-1520-5329-C75F9D453D6C> /usr/libexec/autofsd
      0x7fff86e3b000 -     0x7fff86faeff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.1 (550.13) <1E952BD9-37C6-16BE-B2F0-CD92A6283D37> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
      0x7fff8786c000 -     0x7fff87a2aff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib


Process:         blued [51]
Path:            /usr/sbin/blued
UID:             0

  Thread 7993000    DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 ??? (in blued + 5016) [0x100001398]
      16 ??? (in blued + 152265) [0x1000252c9]
        16 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 77 (in Foundation) [0x7fff81d07903]
          16 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 270 (in Foundation) [0x7fff81d07a24]
            16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
              16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
                16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 70db000    DispatchQueue 2
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 _pthread_wqthread + 353 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886bb8]
        16 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 244 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87887286]
          16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8788775c]
            16 kevent + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87885bba]
  Kernel stack:
    16 kevent + 97 [0x471745]

  Thread 84d2000   
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5e41]
      16 _pthread_start + 331 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5f8e]
        16 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878b09e2]
  Kernel stack:
    16 sleep + 52 [0x487f93]

  Binary Images:
         0x100000000 -        0x100044fff  blued ??? (???) <ECD752C9-F98E-3052-26BF-DC748281C992> /usr/sbin/blued
      0x7fff81cbc000 -     0x7fff81f3dfe7  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.1 (751.14) <767349DB-C486-70E8-7970-F13DB4CDAF37> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
      0x7fff86e3b000 -     0x7fff86faeff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.1 (550.13) <1E952BD9-37C6-16BE-B2F0-CD92A6283D37> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
      0x7fff8786c000 -     0x7fff87a2aff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib


Process:         check_afp [84504]
Path:            /System/Library/Filesystems/AppleShare/check_afp.app/Contents/MacOS/check_afp
UID:             0

  Thread 1140f000   DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 ??? (in check_afp + 5596) [0x1000015dc]
      16 ??? (in check_afp + 12976) [0x1000032b0]
        16 ??? (in check_afp + 6664) [0x100001a08]
          16 ??? (in check_afp + 6520) [0x100001978]
            16 CFRunLoopRun + 70 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e859b6]
              16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
                16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
                  16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 13ad8b7c   DispatchQueue 2
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 _pthread_wqthread + 353 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886bb8]
        16 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 244 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87887286]
          16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8788775c]
            16 kevent + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87885bba]
  Kernel stack:
    16 kevent + 97 [0x471745]

  Thread 13ad6b7c  
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5e41]
      16 _pthread_start + 331 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5f8e]
        16 ??? (in check_afp + 13071) [0x10000330f]
          16 mach_msg_server_once + 285 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878b2417]
            16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 13ad87a8  
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5e41]
      16 _pthread_start + 331 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5f8e]
        16 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878b09e2]
  Kernel stack:
    16 sleep + 52 [0x487f93]

  Binary Images:
         0x100000000 -        0x100004ff7  com.apple.check_afp 2.0 (2.0) <EE865A7B-8CDC-7649-58E1-6FE2B43F7A73> /System/Library/Filesystems/AppleShare/check_afp.app/Contents/MacOS/check_afp
      0x7fff86e3b000 -     0x7fff86faeff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.1 (550.13) <1E952BD9-37C6-16BE-B2F0-CD92A6283D37> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
      0x7fff8786c000 -     0x7fff87a2aff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib


Process:         configd [14]
Path:            /usr/libexec/configd
UID:             0

  Thread 704a3d4    DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 start + 52 (in configd) [0x100001488]
      16 main + 2051 (in configd) [0x100001c9e]
        16 server_loop + 72 (in configd) [0x1000024f4]
          16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
            16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
              16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 6e70000    DispatchQueue 2
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 _pthread_wqthread + 353 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886bb8]
        16 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 244 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87887286]
          16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8788775c]
            16 kevent + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87885bba]
  Kernel stack:
    16 kevent + 97 [0x471745]

  Thread 74a7b7c   
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5e41]
      16 _pthread_start + 331 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5f8e]
        16 plugin_exec + 1440 (in configd) [0x100003c5b]
          16 CFRunLoopRun + 70 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e859b6]
            16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
              16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
                16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 7560000   
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5e41]
      16 _pthread_start + 331 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5f8e]
        16 _io_pm_force_active_settings + 2266 (in PowerManagement) [0x10050f968]
          16 CFRunLoopRun + 70 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e859b6]
            16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
              16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
                16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 75817a8   
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5e41]
      16 _pthread_start + 331 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5f8e]
        16 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878b09e2]
  Kernel stack:
    16 sleep + 52 [0x487f93]

  Thread 8b1db7c   
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 __workq_kernreturn + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878869da]
  Kernel stack:
    16 workqueue_thread_yielded + 562 [0x4cb6ae]

  Binary Images:
         0x100000000 -        0x100026ff7  configd ??? (???) <58C02CBA-5556-4CDC-2763-814C4C7175DE> /usr/libexec/configd
         0x10050c000 -        0x10051dfff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration.PowerManagement 160.0.0 (160.0.0) <0AC3D2ED-919E-29C7-9EEF-629FBDDA6159> /System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PowerManagement.bundle/Contents/MacOS/PowerManagement
      0x7fff86e3b000 -     0x7fff86faeff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.1 (550.13) <1E952BD9-37C6-16BE-B2F0-CD92A6283D37> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
      0x7fff8786c000 -     0x7fff87a2aff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib


Process:         coreaudiod [114]
Path:            /usr/sbin/coreaudiod
UID:             202

  Thread 83b93d4    DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 ??? (in coreaudiod + 3252) [0x100000cb4]
      16 ??? (in coreaudiod + 26505) [0x100006789]
        16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
          16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
            16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 847e3d4    DispatchQueue 2
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 _pthread_wqthread + 353 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886bb8]
        16 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 244 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87887286]
          16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8788775c]
            16 kevent + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87885bba]
  Kernel stack:
    16 kevent + 97 [0x471745]

  Thread 854c000   
  User stack:
    3 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      3 __workq_kernreturn + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878869da]
  Kernel stack:
    3 workqueue_thread_yielded + 562 [0x4cb6ae]

  Binary Images:
         0x100000000 -        0x10001ffef  coreaudiod ??? (???) <A060D20F-A6A7-A3AE-84EC-11D7D7DDEBC6> /usr/sbin/coreaudiod
      0x7fff86e3b000 -     0x7fff86faeff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.1 (550.13) <1E952BD9-37C6-16BE-B2F0-CD92A6283D37> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
      0x7fff8786c000 -     0x7fff87a2aff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib


Process:         coreservicesd [66]
Path:            /System/Library/CoreServices/coreservicesd
UID:             0

  Thread 7994000    DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 ??? (in coreservicesd + 3756) [0x100000eac]
      16 _CoreServicesServerMain + 522 (in CarbonCore) [0x7fff8327a972]
        16 CFRunLoopRun + 70 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e859b6]
          16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
            16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
              16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread 76227a8   
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5e41]
      16 _pthread_start + 331 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5f8e]
        16 read + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87877426]
  Kernel stack:
    16 lo64_unix_scall + 77 [0x29e3fd]
      16 unix_syscall64 + 617 [0x4ee947]
        16 read_nocancel + 158 [0x496add]
          16 write + 312 [0x49634d]
            16 get_pathbuff + 3054 [0x3023db]
              16 tsleep + 105 [0x4881ce]
                16 wakeup + 786 [0x487da7]
                  16 thread_block + 33 [0x226fb5]
                    16 thread_block_reason + 331 [0x226f27]
                      16 thread_dispatch + 1950 [0x226c88]
                        16 machine_switch_context + 753 [0x2a5a37]

  Thread 7622b7c   
  User stack:
    16 thread_start + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5e41]
      16 _pthread_start + 331 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a5f8e]
        16 fmodWatchConsumer + 347 (in CarbonCore) [0x7fff8322f23f]
          16 __semwait_signal + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a79ee]
  Kernel stack:
    16 semaphore_wait_continue + 0 [0x22a0a5]

  Thread 79913d4   
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 _pthread_wqthread + 353 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886bb8]
        16 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 244 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87887286]
          16 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8788775c]
            16 kevent + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87885bba]
  Kernel stack:
    16 kevent + 97 [0x471745]

  Thread 84d2b7c   
  User stack:
    16 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      16 __workq_kernreturn + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878869da]
  Kernel stack:
    16 workqueue_thread_yielded + 562 [0x4cb6ae]

  Thread 9b643d4   
  User stack:
    15 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      15 __workq_kernreturn + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878869da]
  Kernel stack:
    16 workqueue_thread_yielded + 562 [0x4cb6ae]

  Binary Images:
         0x100000000 -        0x100000fff  coreservicesd ??? (???) <D804E55B-4376-998C-AA25-2ADBFDD24414> /System/Library/CoreServices/coreservicesd
      0x7fff831cb000 -     0x7fff834fdfef  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.2 (861.2) <39F3B259-AC2A-792B-ECFE-4F3E72F2D1A5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
      0x7fff86e3b000 -     0x7fff86faeff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.1 (550.13) <1E952BD9-37C6-16BE-B2F0-CD92A6283D37> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
      0x7fff8786c000 -     0x7fff87a2aff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib


Process:         cron [31]
Path:            /usr/sbin/cron
UID:             0

  Thread 75acb7c    DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 ??? (in cron + 2872) [0x100000b38]
      16 ??? (in cron + 3991) [0x100000f97]
        16 sleep + 61 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878f5090]
          16 __semwait_signal + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a79ee]
  Kernel stack:
    16 semaphore_wait_continue + 0 [0x22a0a5]

  Binary Images:
         0x100000000 -        0x100006fff  cron ??? (???) <3C5DCC7E-B6E8-1318-8E00-AB721270BFD4> /usr/sbin/cron
      0x7fff8786c000 -     0x7fff87a2aff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib


Process:         cvmsServ [104]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/cvmsServ
UID:             0

  Thread 761f3d4    DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 ??? (in cvmsServ + 4100) [0x100001004]
      16 ??? (in cvmsServ + 23081) [0x100005a29]
        16 mach_msg_server + 597 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878ea1c8]
          16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Binary Images:
         0x100000000 -        0x100008fff  cvmsServ ??? (???) <6200AD80-4159-5656-8736-B72B7388C461> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/cvmsServ
      0x7fff8786c000 -     0x7fff87a2aff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib


Process:         DirectoryService [11]
Path:            /usr/sbin/DirectoryService
UID:             0

  Thread 70db7a8    DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    16 start + 52 (in DirectoryService) [0x10000da74]
      16 main + 3086 (in DirectoryService) [0x10000e68a]
        16 CFRunLoopRun + 70 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e859b6]
          16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e85c2f]
            16 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff86e867a2]
              16 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff8786ce3a]
  Kernel stack:
    16 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 [0x210aa3]

  Thread <multiple> DispatchQueue 6
  User stack:
    17 start_wqthread + 13 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886a55]
      17 _pthread_wqthread + 353 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87886bb8]
        16 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 231 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff87887279]
          16 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a8ce8]
            16 syscall + 10 (in libSystem.B.dylib) [0x7fff878a92da]
        1 _disp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far updating to Audio Hijack Pro 2.9.6 seems to have avoided the crashes.

Comment: Consider marking this as the accepted answer so others who have the same problem can see the solution. See more [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)